# About the positionning values in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I would like to check an information with you:

Based on this picture:

[image]

is the relative square correct? I think That it must be aligned 50px from the left of the absolute square and not 50px from the left of the window.

Am I correct?

Comment: Can you provide html for this example?

Comment: I don't have, unfortunately, the html code, just this picture!

Comment: If you are talking about the yellow one – that of course depends on whether it is a descendant of the pink one or not. If it is not, then it’s “normal” position would be right below the gray one (its top edge touching the gray one’s bottom edge, and its left edge at the viewport edge) – and offsetting it from that position with `left:50px` and `top:50px` would get it to the position it is shown at. So the only logical conclusion here is that that’s the case – it is not a descendant of the pink one, but independent of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess, because it depends on how the html is formatted. I've created a JSFiddle for you to play with and learn from. All div's are currently nested, with that assumption, you are correct.

[Click here for a JSFiddle with example code](http://jsfiddle.net/c4odx5cL/2/)

Yes, it's semantic html, but this make it easier to understand.

```
 <div class="fixed">
   <div class="absolute">
     <div class="relative">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The css classes for styling.

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #000000;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background: #333333;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;     
}
```

**Note:**
If you look at what is used often, it gets more interesting if you use absolute positioning within relative positioning, like the purple square inside the green square.

- absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
  (not static) ancestor element.
- relative: The element is positioned relative to its normal position, 
  so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position

This allows you to position element within a div within breaking out of the div. More on positioning [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)